# How to get access to pixels from an image in xamarin project?

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I want to get access to pixels colors from an image, but as far as I know Image cannot be used in that way. In my code there is an event Modify where I call a method MakeDarker, but I want to know how can I modify pixels there.

I tried to convert an Image to a bitmap or to byte array, but none of this works for me. Visual Studio doesn't even recognize Bitmap, when I'm typing it despite using Xamarin.Forms.Image.

```
public void Modify(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ImageModify modify = new ImageModify();

    picture = modify.MakeDarker(picture);
}
```

```
class ImageModify
{
    public Image MakeDarker(Image image)
    {
        Image output = new Image();

        for (int i = 0; i < image.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
            {

            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at something like SkiaSharp or ImageEdit for doing image manipulation.  Whatever you do will need to be done on the underlying ImageSource, not the Image control itself

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the [Color struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netframework-4.7.2) from the System.Drawing namespace (don't know if you can use it in Xamarin or if it's specific for Windows based projects) ?

I used it in my own C# projet to collect RGB values of a pixel and it worked well.

Comment: The problem is, that I have to use Bitmap anyway. I have included System.Drawing, but for some reason I cannot use Bitmap.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [Bitmap class](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of the [Image class](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.7.2) to load your images ?